# Convert .vox to .mp3 with JAVA

Tags: java, javasound

I'm trying convert a audio file with extension .vox to .mp3, and I need to do this with Java. I tried using JAVE library, I could convert from wav to mp3, but 
I could not to do with .vox.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        System.out.println("Luis Pavez");
        File source = new File("C:\\audios\\origen\\audio.vox");
        File target = new File("C:\\audios\\origen\\valiente.mp3");
        AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
        audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");//libmp3lame
        audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
        audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
        audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
        EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
        attrs.setFormat("mp3");
        attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
        Encoder encoder = new Encoder();        
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | EncoderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Error

```
it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException: could not find codec parameters
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.parseMultimediaInfo(Encoder.java:532)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:840)
    at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.encode(Encoder.java:713)
    at Convertidor.main(Convertidor.java:30)
```

there is another way to do this?

Comment: Post full stacktrace. Also show imports, I am unable to understand which class is imported from which package.

Comment: Java Sound supports different codecs via a Service Provider Interface. If the SPI is on the class path, any API that uses Java Sound will be able to handle it.